# How to save object (Bitmap image loaded from gallery and string)in gridview?

Tags: android, gridview, adapter, parcelable

```
public class MyObject implements Parcelable{
    Bitmap image;
    String title;

   @Override
   public int describeContents() {
      return 0;
   }
```

I dont understand how to make parcelable
 right yet

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

}
```

Also I use ImageTextAdapter and store my objects in ArrayList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write Bitmap to parcel:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
parcel.writeInt(byteArray.length);
parcel.writeByteArray(byteArray);
```

Read bitmap from parcel:

```
int length = parcel.readInt();
byte[] byteArray = new byte[length];
parcel.readByteArray(byteArray);
image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, length);
```